# module parse failed:Unexpected token you may need an appropiate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4, babel-loader

I searched this issue about..please believe me i have gone through all of the similar ones on stack overflow and on github but couldn't able to solve it. code is in production.. i really need to get it fixed.. please help

```html
error  in ./src/routes/lazy.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (25:11)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var UserDashboard = exports.UserDashboard = (0, _reactLoadable2.default)({
|   loader: function loader() {
>     return import('./dashboard/user');
|   },
|   loading: _Loading2.default

 @ ./src/containers/App.js 43:13-38
 @ ./src/App.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000 (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js babel-polyfill react-hot-loader/patch ./src/index.js
```

```html
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
            options: { minimize: true }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
      },
      // Scss compiler
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
```

Webpack conf
[image: Webpack config]

```js
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "module": "^1.2.5",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "proptypes": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^16.6.3",
    "react-big-calendar": "^0.20.2",
    "react-calendar": "^2.18.1",
    "react-chat-window": "^1.1.1",
    "react-contextmenu": "^2.10.0",
    "react-countdown-clock": "^2.5.0",
    "react-date-picker": "^7.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-headroom": "^2.2.4",
    "react-input-calendar": "^0.5.4",
    "react-intl": "2.4.0",
    "react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "react-mousetrap": "^0.2.0",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.1.1",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-redux": "5.0.7",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.4.0-beta.6",
    "react-scroll-to-component": "^1.0.2",
    "react-select": "^2.1.2",
    "react-toastify": "^4.5.2",
    "react-toastr": "^3.0.0",
    "react-transition-group": "^1.2.0",
    "reactstrap": "^6.3.0",
    "redux": "4.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "validator": "^10.11.0"
```

package.json
[image: package.json]

```js
import Loading from 'Components/Loading';
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

/* 
  User
*/

// User Dashboard
export const UserDashboard = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./dashboard/user'),
  loading: Loading
});
export const UserSuccessCoach = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./user/userSuccessCoach'),
  loading: Loading
});

// List of Dashboard Cards
export const UserMilestones = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./user/userMilestones'),
  loading: Loading
});
export const UserOverdue = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./user/userOverdue'),
  loading: Loading
});
export const UserActions = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./user/userActions'),
  loading: Loading
});
```

lazy.js
[image: lazy.js]

I tried changing the import inside the functions the lazy.js to require. then it gets compiled but when i try to open the application it gives me a new error
[image: new error]

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

let render = () => {
  const MainApp = require('./App').default;
  ReactDOM.render(<MainApp />, rootEl);
};

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./App', () => {
    const NextApp = require('./App').default;
    render(<NextApp />, rootEl);
  });
}

render();
```

Comment: How do webpack know what should be a proper extension for `'./dashboard/user'`? Add simply the extensions to all the imports. Otherwise, please take a look at the option https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolveextensions, maybe this would help.

Comment: Thanks for commenting..  it is giving the same error but i put extension also